# How to work with Illustrator files in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, svg, graphics, adobe-illustrator

Is there any way to open Illustrator files created with .ai or .eps extensions in Android? I'm trying to run these files on Android and move their layers using drag and drop or change their position and also change the color of each layer. Is there a library for this or is it possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no library for rendering Illustrator files. But if you save the files as SVG format, there are libraries for rendering those.

Manipulating the layers via drag and drop is a separate problem then. I don't believe any of the SVG libraries support interativity yet.  You could perhaps save each layer as a separate SVG. Then load them all into a stack of ImageViews. Then drag those about.